# Как выполнить один sql запрос к нескольким базам данных сразу?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Добрый день. Есть около 30 сайтов с бд, которые лежат на разных хостингах. Необходимо создать программку которая бы выполняла sql запрос по нажатию на кнопку во всех базах. Не очень знаком с данной темой, подскажите возможно есть какие то готовые решения или примеры? Куда копать? Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы использовал технологию foreach. Не уверен только что она тебе знакома.

Comment: А обязательно ли делать это ч/з phpmyadmin ? Когда-то писал небольшую вспомогательную тулзу для этого на C#. Так что если это делается не на стороне какого-то сервера, а с рабочей машины - то могу подсказать.

Comment: два пути. Первый через VIEWS от пользователя с нужными правами. Второй через подключение к каждой базе данных по очереди.